# References in example environment (linguex package)

Tags: cross-referencing, linguex

I am using the linguex package to create examples, like this:

```
\ex. First-level example
\a. Second-level example
\b. Second-level example
\a. Third-level example
```

looks like this:

(1) First-level example
   a. Second-level example
   b. Second-level example
      (i) Third-level example

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=totocnumbered,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % globale verwendung im dokument
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes} % anführungszeichen nach sprache wählen
\usepackage{tipa} % ipa-sonderzeichen
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % einrückung bei absätzen unterbinden

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\tableofcontents

\section{Präsuppositionen}
Der Satz in \ref{inferenz} beinhaltet (mindestens) zwei Inferenzen: 
\Next[i] %in diesem Block habe ich die Referenz mit dem Befehl \Next aus dem linguex-Paket erzeugt, im nächsten mit \label
Jenny hat die roten Schuhe gekauft und \Next[ii] sie bereut es. Das Zeichen 
$\glq\gg\grq$  %\grq als schließendes einfaches Anführungszeichen (in Vorlage öffnet es auch)
wird im Folgenden verwendet, um anzuzeigen, dass es sich bei B um eine Präsupposition von A handelt.

\ex. Jenny bereut, dass sie die roten Schuhe gekauft hat. \label{inferenz}
\let\oldalph=\roman\let\alph=\roman %römische Zählung lokal schon in Ebene 2
%Klammerung
\renewcommand{\SubExLeftBracket}{(} 
\renewcommand{\SubExRightBracket}{)}
\a. $\gg$ Jenny hat die roten Schuhe gekauft.
\b. $\gg$ Jenny bereut den Schuhkauf.

Wird die initiale Äußerung nun negiert wie in \ref{negation}, bleibt nur Inferenz \ref{negationa} bestehen, wohingegen Inferenz \ref{negationb} von der Negation betroffen ist.

\ex. Jenny bereut nicht, dass sie die roten Schuhe gekauft hat. \label{negation}
\let\oldalph=\roman\let\alph=\roman %römische Zählung schon in Ebene 2
%Klammerung
\renewcommand{\SubExLeftBracket}{(} 
\renewcommand{\SubExRightBracket}{)}
\a. $\gg$ Jenny hat die roten Schuhe gekauft. \label{negationa}
\b. $\not\gg$ Jenny bereut den Schuhkauf. \label{negationb}

\ex.
\a.[Q:] Fährt Marche mit Homers Auto?
\b.[C:]\# Nein, Homer hat kein Auto.
\c.[C'] Hey, warte mal! Homer hat doch gar kein Auto.

\subsection{Quantoren}
\ex. \a. Alle Linguisten sind Nerds.
\b. $\forall$x (Linguisten(x) $\rightarrow$ Nerd(x))

\ex. Georg ist immer müde, während er Nachtschicht hat. \\
$\not \rightarrow$ Georg ist immer müde.

\ex. Immer $\lbrace$während er Nachtschicht hat$\rbrace_{Restriktion}$ [ist Georg müde]$_{Nukleus}$

\subsection{Experiment}

\ex. \a.[Con 1:~] Komplementsatz, Brückenverb
     \b.[Con 2:~] Temporalsatz
     \b.[Con 3:~] Semifaktiver Komplementsatz

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \textit{wissen} & \textit{erfahren} & \textit{auch} & \textit{wieder}\\
\hline
\textit{Nein,\dots} (Projektion) & 38,24 & 51,96 & 87,25 & 99,02\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Ergebnisse}
\end{table}

\section{Kausalsätze}
Typischerweise weisen Hauptsätze V2-Stellung auf (vgl. Beispiel \ref{v2}), wohingegen Nebensätze mit VL-Stellung gebildet werden wie in Beispiel \ref{vl}.

\ex.
\ag. Sam \textbf{isst} nur Salat.\\ 
Sam eats only salad.\\
$\grq$Sam only eats salad.'\label{v2}
\bg. Sam ist sehr mager, weil er nur Salat \textbf{isst.}\\
Sam is very skinny because he only salad eats.\\
$\grq$Sam is very skinny because he only eats salad.'\label{vl}

\ex.
\ag. Niemand$_i$ war verärgert, weil er$_i$ nicht eingeladen \textbf{war.}\\
    nobody$_i$ was angry because he$_i$ not invited was\\
    $\grq$Nobody$_i$ was angry because he$_i$ \textbf{was} not invited.'
\b.*Niemand$_i$ war verärgert, weil er$_i$ \textbf{war} nicht eingeladen.

\ex.
\ag. Die Straße ist weiß, weil es geschneit \textbf{hat.}\\
    the road is white because it snowed has.\\
    $\grq$The road is white because it has snowed.'
\b. CAUSE ($\exists$ e$_1$ [snow (e$_1$)], $\exists$ e$_2$ [white (street, e$_2$)])

\end{document}
```

I have already changed that roman numbers appear in the second level.

Now I have a problem concerning the references. At the moment they appear as (1-i), (1-ii) and so on in the text (1 for the first level and i/ii for the second). How is it possible that only the second level is printed, just as (i) and (ii)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example was too big. Please read what is a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Your redefinition of the label is weird. You should use the following definition:

```
\renewcommand{\SubExlabel}{\SubExLBr\Exroman{SubExNo}\SubExRBr}
```

If you use the following definition, the references will be set correct.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theSubExNo}{%
 \hbox{\if@noftnote\theExLBr\Exroman{SubExNo}\theExRBr\else\theFnExLBr\Exalph{SubExNo}\theFnExRBr\fi}%
}
\makeatother
```

Here a small example to demonstrate the behaviour:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,listof=totocnumbered,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\SubExlabel}{\SubExLBr\Exroman{SubExNo}\SubExRBr}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theSubExNo}{%
 \hbox{\if@noftnote\theExLBr\Exroman{SubExNo}\theExRBr\else\theFnExLBr\Exalph{SubExNo}\theFnExRBr\fi}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ex. First-level example

\a.  \label{foo}Second-level example
\b. Second-level example 
\a. Third-level example 
\b. Third level\label{bar}


Text \ref{foo} and \ref{bar}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this platform so I’m not yet used to your habbits. I tried your version, but it did not work, instead it gave me several errors:! Undefined control sequence.
\theSubExNo ->\hbox {\if@noftnote \theExLBr
\Exroman {SubExNo}\theExRBr \els...
l.19

Comment: @kweku: Did you try my example? Your example above produces errors.

Comment: Yes, I tried your example. But it does not work. I copied one of the error messages. Actually I am new to LaTeX and do not really understand your solution. I will try to read and understand the documentations – With my code I don’t get any errors, that’s weird.

Comment: @kweku: Really weird ;-). Three other users tested the example with the same result: [WFM](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8748894#8748894)<-klick

Comment: Such a pity I can’t join the chat (as a newbie with only 1 R point)! Well, I dont know why, but it gives me that error: '! Undefined control sequence.
\theSubExNo ->\hbox {\if@noftnote \theExLBr
\Exroman {SubExNo}\theExRBr \els...
l.19'

Comment: The problem is solved. :-) Marco Daniel, your code works fine now. The problem was that I was running an old version of TeXLive (2009, which seems to be the standard in Ubuntu 12.04), so I did an update to TexLive 2012 and now everything works fine.

Comment: Btw, I took the redefinition of the label from the documentation, so this weird code was not my idea ;)

Comment: @kweku: But this redefinition can lead to unwanted changes for counters in the environment ;-)